# How to render QStringView using QPainter?

Tags: qt, qwidget, qstring, qpainter

I'm implementing a custom text layouting engine and I need to render a lot of `QStringView`s. But `QPainter`'s `drawText` overloads only accept `QString`s. Converting all these `QStringView`s to `QString`s just to draw them is terribly inefficient and kinda defeats the purpose of using string views in the first place.

Is there a way to avoid intantiating many `QString`s just to use the `drawText` functions? Maybe there's a way to create a "fake" `QString`? Or maybe there is a lower-level (but still cross-platform) text drawing method?
Thanks!

Comment: No, no chance yet. But you can provide a patch to Qt and maybe it's getting integrated.

Comment: Have you looked at `QStaticText` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstatictext.html#details ?

Comment: @Fryz: Yes, I looked at it, unfortunately can't use QStaticText because of the custom layouting requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't found a way to use `QStringView` specifically for this purpose.

However, I did find a way to create QStrings while avoiding expensive copying.

QString has a static method named `fromRawData` that allows to create a QString from pre-existing pointer and length. Using this method, it seems that I was able to avoid copying.

Here's the description of this method:

[image]

It worked great for my case, however I must admit I haven't profiled the resulting code and relied on the information from the docs. Please check it for yourself.